# Applying style inside LI

Tags: css, css-selectors

A program generates the following HTML

```
<blah blah blah> 
  <li class="compact class_x class_y">
  <label class=label/>
  <select>...</select>
  </li>
<blah blah blah>
```

Is there a way to apply styles to the li and the labels and select inside it, but no others?. In other words, whenever I have a compact style, I want to apply changes to the li, the label and select inside. The label has a class already, and the select has no class. I can't modify the html.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to use

```
.compact {
/* li styles */
}

.compact label {
/* label styles in compact class */
}

.compact select{
/* select styles in compact class */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<blah class="something">
    <li></li>
    <label />
    <select></select>
</blah>
```

**CSS:**

```
.something > li {}
.something > label {}
.something > select {}
```

You can replace .something with whatever `<blah>` is.  I assume you have multiple of these and each needs to be different?

Comment: Hi, the blah blah was not important. The solution given by mookamafoob was what I needed. Thank you very much for your time.